# Change scrollbar style only when horizontal

Tags: html, css, webkit, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

I have a horizontal scroll section on my website but i want to change the scroll style, iv'e managed to change the scroll bar style using '''::-webkit-scrollbar''' tag but it also affects the vertical scroll. I only want to change the scroll bar when its to slide content horizontally.

Any responses are greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are more selectors available. Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `::webkit-scrollbar` with particular class.
For example:
Let the container be '.scroll-content'

```
.scroll-content::-webkit-scrollbar-track{-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);background-color: #ccc;}
.scroll-content::-webkit-scrollbar{width: 5px;height: 5px;background-color: #ccc;}
.scroll-content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{background-color: #ff7043;}
```

But this method is not applicable in Mozilla Firefox

Comment: i personally prefer properly formatted CSS, it's much more readable than the minified one ^ and in places like S.O. that is better because it's more conductive towards understanding (which should be preferred to mindless copy-pasting).

Answer (score 1):

Use the pseudo-class selectors:

```css
:horizontal
:vertical
:decrement
:increment
:start
:end 
:double-button
:single-button
:no-button
:corner-present
:window-inactive
```

Working demo: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/demartini/pen/VwepNbo).

More info [here](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/).

Note: this only works on webkit browsers.